# For loop each workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through every worksheet in my file and if certain word is found in workbook delete that cell with other eleven cells below.

I give up. My code doesn't work. Can't figure out why.

Can someone help me please?

```
Sub forEachWs()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim find As Range

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Sheets(ws).Select
    Set find = Cells.find(What:="nieusprawiedliwiona", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not find Is Nothing Then find.Activate

    Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(11, 0)).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete

Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got it working.

```
Sub forEachWs()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim find As Range

For Each ws In Worksheets
    MsgBox (ws.Name)
    ws.Select
    Set find = Cells.find(What:="nieusprawiedliwiona", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not find Is Nothing Then find.Activate

    Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(11, 0)).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete

Next ws
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Try without the select/activate:

```vb
Sub forEachWs()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim find As Range

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        
        Set find = ws.Cells.find(What:="nieusprawiedliwiona", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not find Is Nothing Then find.Resize(12,1).EntireRow.Delete

    Next ws
End Sub
```